# Which Alexa SDK for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I'm a bit confused about Alexa SDK for node js, there is "alexa-sdk" and "ask-sdk-core". Which one should I choose?

Comment: I would just pick one and see if it works for you. Without knowing your exact requirements and context how you're planning to use this all answers you'll get here are probably a guess and if it is based on actual usage knowledge it is still to be seen if it is a fit for your use case.

Comment: On GitHub says `ask-sdk-core: Core SDK package contains basic components and default implementations of ASK SDK v2 for Node.js.`. So i think `alexa-sdk` is a wrapper of the functions of `ask-sdk-core`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my answer here: https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ASK-SDK-Migration-Guide.html?highlight=migrate `alexa-sdk` is the old SDK.